# How to resolve a C2064 error in C++ WxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to encapsulate all the GUI of a certain page in my app in one function, so that my mainFrame function is much cleaner and so that I can create the entire Gui by calling just one function, however I am getting a C2064 error when I am trying to make the mainFrame the event handler for a button, can anyone help? below I have provided my script:

MainFrame Cpp file:

```
#include "MainFrame.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/scrolwin.h>
#include <fstream>

void CollectCustomerInfoGUI(wxPanel* BG) {
    MainFrame* mainFrame;
    wxTextCtrl* CustomerName = new wxTextCtrl(BG, wxID_ANY, "Enter Name", wxPoint(380, 150), wxSize(700, 35), wxTE_CENTER | wxNO_BORDER | wxTE_NO_VSCROLL);
    wxFont InfoFont = CustomerName->GetFont();
    InfoFont.SetPointSize(17);
    CustomerName->SetFont(InfoFont);
    CustomerName->SetBackgroundColour("#04BF68");
    CustomerName->SetForegroundColour("#F0F1F2");
    wxTextCtrl* CustomerGender = new wxTextCtrl(BG, wxID_ANY, "Male / Female", wxPoint(380, 220), wxSize(700, 35), wxTE_CENTER | wxNO_BORDER | wxTE_NO_VSCROLL);
    CustomerGender->SetFont(InfoFont);
    CustomerGender->SetBackgroundColour("#04BF68");
    CustomerGender->SetForegroundColour("#F0F1F2");
    wxTextCtrl* CustomerAddress = new wxTextCtrl(BG, wxID_ANY, "Enter Adress", wxPoint(380, 290), wxSize(700, 35), wxTE_CENTER | wxNO_BORDER | wxTE_NO_VSCROLL);
    CustomerAddress->SetFont(InfoFont);
    CustomerAddress->SetBackgroundColour("#04BF68");
    CustomerAddress->SetForegroundColour("#F0F1F2");
    wxTextCtrl* CustomerAge = new wxTextCtrl(BG, wxID_ANY, "Enter Age", wxPoint(380, 360), wxSize(700, 35), wxTE_CENTER | wxNO_BORDER | wxTE_NO_VSCROLL);
    CustomerAge->SetFont(InfoFont);
    CustomerAge->SetBackgroundColour("#04BF68");
    CustomerAge->SetForegroundColour("#F0F1F2");
    wxTextCtrl* CustomerMobileNum = new wxTextCtrl(BG, wxID_ANY, "Enter Mobile Number", wxPoint(380, 430), wxSize(700, 35), wxTE_CENTER | wxNO_BORDER | wxTE_NO_VSCROLL);
    CustomerMobileNum->SetFont(InfoFont);
    CustomerMobileNum->SetBackgroundColour("#04BF68");
    CustomerMobileNum->SetForegroundColour("#F0F1F2");
    wxTextCtrl* CustomerCreditCardNumber = new wxTextCtrl(BG, wxID_ANY, "Enter Credit Card Number", wxPoint(380, 500), wxSize(700, 35), wxTE_CENTER | wxNO_BORDER | wxTE_NO_VSCROLL);
    CustomerCreditCardNumber->SetFont(InfoFont);
    CustomerCreditCardNumber->SetBackgroundColour("#04BF68");
    CustomerCreditCardNumber->SetForegroundColour("#F0F1F2");
    wxTextCtrl* CustomerID = new wxTextCtrl(BG, wxID_ANY, "EnterID", wxPoint(380, 570), wxSize(700, 35), wxTE_CENTER | wxNO_BORDER | wxTE_NO_VSCROLL);
    CustomerID->SetFont(InfoFont);
    CustomerID->SetBackgroundColour("#04BF68");
    CustomerID->SetForegroundColour("#F0F1F2");
    wxButton* CustomerInfoButton = new wxButton(BG, wxID_ANY, "Submit Data", wxPoint(580, 645), wxSize(300, 60), wxNO_BORDER);
    CustomerInfoButton->SetFont(InfoFont);
    CustomerInfoButton->SetBackgroundColour("#01261C");
    CustomerInfoButton->SetForegroundColour("#04BF68");
    CustomerInfoButton->SetFocus();

    CustomerName->Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, &MainFrame::StringEmptier);
    CustomerGender->Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, &MainFrame::StringEmptier);
    CustomerAddress->Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, &MainFrame::StringEmptier);
    CustomerAge->Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, &MainFrame::StringEmptier);
    CustomerMobileNum->Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, &MainFrame::StringEmptier);
    CustomerCreditCardNumber->Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, &MainFrame::StringEmptier);
    CustomerID->Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, &MainFrame::StringEmptier);
    /* with my trial and error I have found the root of cause to be this line*/ CustomerInfoButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, std::bind(&MainFrame::CustomerInfoBTN, mainFrame, std::placeholders::_1, CustomerName, CustomerGender, CustomerAddress, CustomerAge, CustomerMobileNum, CustomerCreditCardNumber, CustomerID));
}

MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title) {
    wxPanel* BG = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
    BG->SetBackgroundColour("#038C73");

    wxStaticText* AgencyName = new wxStaticText(BG, wxID_ANY, ">>>> Muhammad's LLC <<<<", wxPoint(175, 25), wxSize(1100, 90), wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    AgencyName->SetForegroundColour("#FDFFFF");
    wxFont font = AgencyName->GetFont();
    font.SetPointSize(35);
    AgencyName->SetFont(font);

    BG->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &MainFrame::OnPaint, this);

    CollectCustomerInfoGUI(BG);
}

void MainFrame::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event) {
    wxPanel* BG = dynamic_cast<wxPanel*>(event.GetEventObject());
    if (!BG)
        return;

    wxPaintDC dc(BG); // Use a wxPaintDC to draw on the panel

    // Set the drawing color
    dc.SetPen(wxPen(wxColour("#038C73"), 2)); // Blue color with 2-pixel width
    dc.SetBrush(wxBrush(wxColour("#025949"), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID));

    // Draw a rectangle at position (10, 10) with width 100 and height 50
    dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(15, 125, 1420, 610, 10);
}
void MainFrame::StringEmptier(wxFocusEvent& event)
{
    // Clear the text when the wxTextCtrl receives focus
    wxTextCtrl* textCtrl = dynamic_cast<wxTextCtrl*>(event.GetEventObject());
    if (textCtrl) {
        textCtrl->SetValue("");
    }
    event.Skip();
}
void MainFrame::CustomerInfoBTN(wxCommandEvent& event, wxTextCtrl* CustmeName, wxTextCtrl* CustmeGender, wxTextCtrl* CustmeAddress, wxTextCtrl* CustmeAge, wxTextCtrl* CustmeMobileNum, wxTextCtrl* CustmeCreditNum, wxTextCtrl* CustmeIdD) {
    wxTextCtrl* CstmerName = CustmeName;
    wxTextCtrl* CstmerGender = CustmeGender;
    wxTextCtrl* CstmerAddress = CustmeAddress;
    wxTextCtrl* CstmerAge = CustmeAge;
    wxTextCtrl* CstmerMobileNum = CustmeMobileNum;
    wxTextCtrl* CstmerCreditNum = CustmeCreditNum;
    wxTextCtrl* CstmerIDDD = CustmeIdD;
    
    Customers CsmClass;
    
    CstmerName->Show(false);
    CstmerGender->Show(false);
    CstmerAddress->Show(false);
    CstmerAge->Show(false);
    CstmerMobileNum->Show(false);
    CstmerCreditNum->Show(false);
    CstmerIDDD->Show(false);

    std::ofstream out("old-customers.txt", std::ios::app); {
        CsmClass.Name = CstmerName->GetValue().ToStdString();
        CsmClass.Gender = CstmerGender->GetValue().ToStdString();
        CsmClass.Address = CstmerAddress->GetValue().ToStdString();
        CsmClass.Age = std::stoi(CstmerAge->GetValue().ToStdString());
        CsmClass.MobileNum = std::stoi(CstmerMobileNum->GetValue().ToStdString());
        CsmClass.CreditCardNum = std::stoi(CstmerCreditNum->GetValue().ToStdString());
        CsmClass.CustomerID = std::stoi(CstmerIDDD->GetValue().ToStdString());
    }
    out << "\nName: " << CsmClass.Name << "\nGender: " << CsmClass.Gender << "\nAddress: " << CsmClass.Address << "\nAge: " << CsmClass.Age
        << "\nMobile Number: " << CsmClass.MobileNum << "\nCredit Card Number: " << CsmClass.CreditCardNum << "\nCustomer ID: " << CsmClass.CustomerID;
    out.close();
    wxMessageBox("Customer info has been succesfully stored!" ,"INFO", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION, this);
}
```

And my MainFrame.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include <WX/WX.h>
#include <wx/scrolwin.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>

class MainFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MainFrame(const wxString& title);
    void StringEmptier(wxFocusEvent& event);
    void CustomerInfoBTN(wxCommandEvent& event, wxTextCtrl* CustmeName, wxTextCtrl* CustmeGender, wxTextCtrl* CustmeAddress, wxTextCtrl* CustmeAge, wxTextCtrl* CustmeMobileNum, wxTextCtrl* CustmeCreditNum, wxTextCtrl* CustmeIdD);
private:
    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event);
};

class Customers {
public:
    std::string Name{};
    std::string Gender{};
    std::string Address{};
    int Age{};
    int MobileNum{};
    int CreditCardNum{};
    int CustomerID{};
};
class Cabs {



};
class Booking {



};
class Charges {



};
```

Exact error from the output terminal on visual studio:

```
Build started at 7:14 PM...
1>------ Build started: Project: TravelManager, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>MainFrame.cpp
1>C:\Users\Muhammad Hadi\Downloads\wxWidgets-3.2.4\include\wx\event.h(547,9): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>(compiling source file 'MainFrame.cpp')
1>C:\Users\Muhammad Hadi\Downloads\wxWidgets-3.2.4\include\wx\event.h(547,9):
1>the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
1>  D:\C++\TravelManager\TravelManager\MainFrame.cpp(44,17):
1>  see reference to function template instantiation 'void wxEvtHandler::Bind<wxEventTypeTag<wxFocusEvent>,void(__cdecl MainFrame::* )(wxFocusEvent &)>(const EventTag &,const Functor &,int,int,wxObject *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            EventTag=wxEventTypeTag<wxFocusEvent>,
1>            Functor=void (__cdecl MainFrame::* )(wxFocusEvent &)
1>        ]
1>  C:\Users\Muhammad Hadi\Downloads\wxWidgets-3.2.4\include\wx\event.h(3888,36):
1>  see reference to class template instantiation 'wxEventFunctorFunctor<EventTag,Functor>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            EventTag=wxEventTypeTag<wxFocusEvent>,
1>            Functor=void (__cdecl MainFrame::* )(wxFocusEvent &)
1>        ]
1>  C:\Users\Muhammad Hadi\Downloads\wxWidgets-3.2.4\include\wx\event.h(538,18):
1>  while compiling class template member function 'void wxEventFunctorFunctor<EventTag,Functor>::operator ()(wxEvtHandler *,wxEvent &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            EventTag=wxEventTypeTag<wxFocusEvent>,
1>            Functor=void (__cdecl MainFrame::* )(wxFocusEvent &)
1>        ]
1>Done building project "TravelManager.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 7:14 PM and took 03.092 seconds ==========
```

I tried to set MainFrame the event handler by requesting a refrence to mainframe on calling the function, yet it just resulted in the C2064 error popping up

Comment: Could you include the exact and complete error message including line numbers and indicate which line that is?

Comment: Okay let me add the exact error

Comment: Sorry, just updated and added the complete error

Comment: Looks like that `Bind` function cannot take a pointer to member, which is understandable, since pointers to members are weird.

Comment: As the message tries to tell you, the problem is the focus event bindings. You need to also pass `this`, as you do with `OnPaint`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a pointer to a member function, such as `StringEmptier`, you also need to pass object to call it on, e.g. often `this` but in this case it is `mainFrame`. So all your calls like

```cpp
    CustomerName->Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, &MainFrame::StringEmptier);
```

should actually be

```cpp
    CustomerName->Bind(wxEVT_SET_FOCUS, &MainFrame::StringEmptier, mainFrame);
```

instead.

BTW, it's pretty weird that you use "trial and error" to find the line with the error, when you have the line numbers directly in the error messages.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but apparently adding the "this" to all the binds just resulted in 
E0258 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function error, can you help further?

Comment: Edited the answer, I didn't notice you were not doing it in a member function of `MainFrame`. I'd also recommend looking at least a bit into function pointers in C++.